# Dynamic script that restores backups based on restore point, trying to do while loop to get last date

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-backups

One problem I have got is that my while loop logic isn't retrieving the last backup_finish_date. Because I want it to say no recovery and the last backupfile to say recovery.

```
DECLARE @BackupCounter INT,
        @RestorePoint  DATETIME

SET @BackupCounter = 1

WHILE ( @BackupCounter <= (SELECT TOP 1 backup_finish_date
                           FROM   #temptable_backups) )
  BEGIN
      SELECT TOP 1 @RestorePoint = Max(backup_finish_date)
      FROM   #temptable_backups
      GROUP  BY backup_finish_date
      ORDER  BY backup_finish_date

      IF @DiffDate IS NOT NULL
        SET @FullBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy
                             + '  FROM DISK = ''' + @FullBackupFile
                             + ''' WITH  NORECOVERY,  MOVE '''
                             + @DatabaseName + ''' TO '''
                             + @FullBackupFileCopy + ''', MOVE '''
                             + @FullBackupFileCopyldf + '''   TO '''
                             + @FullBackupFileCopylocationldf
                             + ''' , NORECOVERY,NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, STATS = 5'

      DELETE FROM #temptable_backups
      WHERE  backup_finish_date = @RestorePoint;

      PRINT @FullBackupSQL

      SET @DiffBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy
                           + ' FROM  DISK = ''' + @DiffBackupFile
                           +
      ''' WITH  NORECOVERY,FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5'

      DELETE FROM #temptable_backups
      WHERE  backup_finish_date = @RestorePoint

      PRINT @DiffBackupSQL

      SET @FullBackupSQL = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @DatabaseNameCopy
                           + '  FROM DISK = ''' + @FullBackupFile
                           + ''' WITH  RECOVERY'

      PRINT @FullBackupSQL

      SET @BackupCounter = 1
  END
```

Comment: When I try print the Result out I get the files printed out continuously.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, Management Studio

Comment: Please use WITH RECOVERY

Comment: Shouldn't be NoRecovery then Recovery, For example Only FULL - restore FULL with recovery
FULL and LOGS - restore FULL no recovery, all logs apart from last LOG with no recovery, last LOG set to Recovery
FULL and DIFF - restore FULL with no recovery and DIFF with Recovery
FULL, DIFF and LOGS - Restore FULL, DIFF and all LOGS with no recovery, last LOG set to recovery. @BogdanSahlean